# A lot derived classes without functonality only to "know" their type

Tags: c#, .net, oop, design-patterns

I think there is a better solution for the following problem.

Let's say we have the following structure of classes:

```
class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

class Bar1 : Foo
{

}

class Bar2 : Foo
{

}

class Bar3 : Foo
{

}
//.. A lot more of these Foo derivations
```

The derived classes has no functionality. 
The following examples give an idea what the classes are for:

- Access a specific object from a specific type (object from type Bar3 with Id 5) in a list of Foo objects.
- Displaying different data in a GUI related to a specific object from type Foo.

Is there a better way to identify one of these objects without derivating them?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use empty interfaces (so called markers) or attributes for same purposes.

Comment: Both of the issues sound like UI issues, not entity modelling issues. Depending on the UI framework you can have multiple Views and ViewModels with just the data fields you need to display. Searching for separate "types" depends on how you determine the type. It could be an Enum field or the result of a query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they are *semantically* the same and have no meaning to derivatives, you could create an `Enum`:

```
public enum SomeGreatEnum
{
   Bar1,
   Bar2,
   Bar3
}
```

And add a property to `Foo`:

```
class Foo
{
    public SomeGreatEnum SomeGreatEnum { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can:

1. Filter:

   ```
   foos.Where(x => x.SomeGreatEnum == SomeGreatEnum.Bar1);
   ```
2. Bind to GUI based on enum type.

Comment: And what if they are not semantically the same? Lets say Bar1 is an entity that User X has do handle and Bar2 is handled by User Y.

Comment: How would both users handle each entity? Would they do different things?

Comment: The two different entities are tasks in a workflow witch can be handled different by different users and as described should show different data in a GUI.

Comment: @Stofa You can totally work with this for different handling based on enum value. It would save you the time of creating an empty type for each one.

Answer (score 2):

Better to use enumeration instead.

```
class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public FooKind Kind { get; set; }
}
```

Child class should enhance functionality of Parent class.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason this feels like a problem is that there are other parts of your code that are not very object oriented.

Let me explain. Lets assume you go with the enum option. Then, whenever you want to do something with a Foo, that is different for each kind of Foo, you will need to use a switch statement, or select part of the items in the collection through some other method (like the .Where call in the enum example). As the code evolves, you will have so many of these statements that it will begin to feel wrong. Every different action over a Foo, will need to deal with all kinds of Foos. Also, Whenever you make changes to these parts of your code, you will have to make sure you separate them correctly, and that means that you will need to understand the logic behind that behaviour for all kinds of Foo at once.

If there is *any* chance the logic is going to get more complex, I would advise to use the interface and many classes approach over the enum approach.

Now, currently in your code, you are probably managing the difference in behaviour outside of the Foos. In order to make it more OO, you would want to let the Foos manage that difference themselves.

Comment: Hello Guido. Thanks for you answer. You're right and this is also a reason why i asked this question. My problem is, that those Bar Objects are Entities and i don't really want to implement all the stuff related to them into the Domainlayer... So i tried to find a better way. Maybe i had to explain this in the question.

Comment: My guess is that if you need to treat them differently in the GUI, they are already in the domain layer. Are they not? Maybe you should make their presence explicit. This does not necessarily mean replicating the Entities, the domain object/objects can be different. It all comes down to the question: Are trying to avoid complexity in code, or avoiding to codify the complexity already present in the domain? In my experience, the latter will always result in ugly code in the long term.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the visitor pattern:

```
    class Visitor
    {
        public void Visit(Bar1 foo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bar1 ID:" + foo.Id);
        }

        public void Visit(Bar2 foo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bar2 ID:" + foo.Id);
        }

        public void Visit(Bar3 foo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bar3 ID:" + foo.Id);
        }
    }
```

I slightly modified your classes:

```
    abstract class Foo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public abstract void Accept(Visitor visitor);
    }

    class Bar1 : Foo
    {
        public override void Accept(Visitor visitor)
        {
            visitor.Visit(this);
        }
    }

    class Bar2 : Foo
    {
        public override void Accept(Visitor visitor)
        {
            visitor.Visit(this);
        }
    }

    class Bar3 : Foo
    {
        public override void Accept(Visitor visitor)
        {
            visitor.Visit(this);
        }
    }
```

and now to make it all work:

```
        var visitor = new Visitor();
        var lst = new List<Foo> 
            { 
                new Bar1() { Id = 1 }, 
                new Bar2() { Id = 2 }, 
                new Bar3() { Id = 3 } 
            };
        foreach(var element in lst) 
        {
            element.Accept(visitor);
        }

        /* Output is:
         *
         * Bar1 ID:1
         * Bar2 ID:2
         * Bar3 ID:3
         */
```

The full design pattern calls for `Visitor` to implement an interface, which will be used in the signature of the `Accept` methods.

You can find more information about the Visitor design pattern [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) and an example of it being used in the .Net framework [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

The main drawback of using this design pattern is the coupling it creates between the visitor(s) and the concrete elements who are being visited.

For instance, when adding a new class `Bar4 : Foo`, it would need to override the `Accept` method and the `Visitor` would also need to updated with a new `Visit` method overload.